# Setcontent of tinymce from external file

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

How can I load a specific html template inside my TinyMCE editor?
I saw this code but it doesnt work in me;

`$.get("hello.html", tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent)`;

and then I tried this code so that it will automatically load;

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $.get("../../../../app/views/tools/prooftemplate.phtml", tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent);
});
```

but it doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

You need to pass along the data to a callback function then use that data in the function as I've done. Data from the file is then passed to "d" so we update tinyMCE with the newly loaded data.

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $.get("../../../../app/views/tools/prooftemplate.phtml", function(d){
        tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent(d);
    });
});
```

Comment: It says Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) But I am very sure of my location of file. Thanks for the response.